# The character on the screen won't move (pygame)

Tags: pygame, sprite

For some reason, the arrow keys will not move the "guy.png" sprite. Does anyone have an explanation as to why? Yes, the sprite does show up on screen, and yes, guy.png is under the same folder as the project.

code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500), 0, 32)
guy_sprite = pygame.image.load("guy.png")
wall_sprite = pygame.image.load("wall.png")

class guy_class(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, surface):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = 250
        self.y = 250
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = 0
        self.sprite = guy_sprite

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.K_UP:
            self.vy = -1
        elif event.type == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.vy = 1
        elif event.type == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.vx = -1
        elif event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.vx = 1

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y += self.vy

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.sprite, (int(self.x), int(self.y)))

    def position(self):
        return self.x, self.y

class wall_class(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, surface):
        self.x = 100
        self.y = 250
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = 0
        self.sprite = wall_sprite

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.sprite, (self.x, self.y))

def end_game():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
guy = guy_class(screen)
wall = wall_class(screen)

while True:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    guy.move()
    guy.draw(screen)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            end_game()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            guy.event(event)

    clock.tick(100)
    pygame.display.update()
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your sprite is not moving is because you are checking for type instead of key in your guy event function.

So change it to this:

```
def event(self, event):
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        self.vy = -1
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        self.vy = 1
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        self.vx = -1
    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        self.vx = 1
```

you should also check for the KEY_UP event, so your sprite will stop when you will release the key.